# how can I color on selected listtile with ListView? everything not works in my code

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried all things on stackoverflow answers.
but I could not found answer.
please help me please..

As you know, I used data from http api.

**I don't know why I can't color selected listtile.**
I tried cover listtile with **InkWell, Ink, Container and so on..
but they do not work.**
please help me.

here is my flutter code.

```
Widget _patientList(context, snapshot) {
    bool isSelected = false;
    int selectedIndex;
    List<bool> _selected = List.generate(200, (n) => false);
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          child: TextField(controller: patientController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.4), filled: true,
              hintText: '이름'),
            onChanged: (text){
            setState(() {
            });
            },
          ),),

                TextButton(
                    child: Text('조회',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  onPressed: (){
                      patientController.clear();
                  },
                )
          ])),
          SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05),
          SafeArea(
            child: Scrollbar(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    child:
                         ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                        return  Container(
                          color: selectedIndex == position? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                            child: ListTile(
                            title: InkWell(
                            child: Text(
                          snapshot.data.data[position].name +
                              '(' +
                              snapshot.data.data[position].birth +
                              '/' +
                              snapshot.data.data[position].sex +
                              ')',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex = position;
                            });
                              patientId = snapshot.data.data[position].patientId;
                              print(patientId);
                        },)));
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Divider(height: 0, thickness: 2,);
                      },
                    )


                )))]));
  }
```

- 

print(patientId);
is work well. I think it means selecting value works well.
but I can't color selected **listtile.**

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing and could do with improvements. Regardless, have you tried wrapping your `ListTile` with a `Container` and giving it a color?

Comment: Of course, but they both do not worked...

Comment: 'Container(
                          color: selectedIndex == position? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                            child: ListTile('

Comment: If you follow the question guidelines on StackOverflow and provide us with reproducible piece of code, we may be able to help you. Otherwise it may be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedIndex` only exists inside this function, it should be a parameter on the StatefullWidget.

Calling `setState()` will recall your `build()` function, on your code you are basically restarting the `selectedIndex` every time you click on a tile